# Select divs after same level element

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can I select one element after a specific element? In e.g.

```html
<div class="general">
    <div class="inner">Foo 1</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 3</div>
    <div class="header">Bar</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 4</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 5</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 6</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 7</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo ...</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo n</div>
</div>
```

How can I select the 4 `div.inner` after `.header` without selecting first three `div.inner`?

FYI, I am unable to modify any HTML, I am able to modify only CSS.

**EDIT**
I have not made the correct question. I just need all the `.inner` elements after `.header` skipping the first `n` ('n' might change in the future) elements.

**EDIT**
Goal is to style "Foo 7" to "Foo n", inclusive.

Comment: like this: https://jsfiddle.net/so9gac6h/?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, now that the question has been edited once more, again making my previous answer looking wrong, I change my answer once more to make it fit the question:

You can use several `+` selectors to "count up" to the first sibling that *should*  be affected and then add a `~` selector after that to select all following siblings  with the same class:

```css
.header + .inner + .inner  + .inner ~.inner {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="general">
<div class="inner">Foo 1</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 2</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 3</div>
    <div class="header">Bar</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 4</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 5</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 6</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo 7</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo ...</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo ...</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo ...</div>
    <div class="inner">Foo n</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have made a wrong question, I am editing it right now.

Comment: I just edited the question to make it more understandable

Answer (score 2):

use the general sibling selector ~ as it will only match if the sibling comes afterwards.

`.header ~ .inner { }`

Answer (score 0):

That's the best way to get what you're looking for
I hope I get it right

```
.header ~ .inner
```

[demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/tzc42oLw/)